# Is AppArmor used in production environments?

Tags: linux, selinux, apparmor

I was recently having a conversation with a friend about his server system (he does a lot of self-hosting) and he mentioned he was in the middle of configuring SELinux. I was curious about the comparison of that over AppArmor for his use case. Of course, I've always heard that SELinux is more secure due to the considerable amount of fine-grained control it gives you, but that AppArmor was a lot easier to configure.

He mentioned that AppArmor was very "hobbyist focused", so I was curious about how much AppArmor is actually used on production systems. Any insights would be helpful.

I guess the reasonable follow-up here is what considerations and what kinds of systems each are used for. Are both used together in some high-security environments?

Comment: While it’s highly opinion based. I can confirm AppArmor gets used in production systems. It’s often easier to maintain and doesn’t really offer much more protection than SELinix does in specific usecase.

Comment: AppArmor logs denies, fails and detections in /var/log/kern.log or /var/log/messages. After years of running it, I never saw one entry of it doing anything useful on my servers. The only time it did something was when it interfered with unbound, and did that in a bad way (a false positive in fact). Made me disable and remove it entirely. So yeah, your mileage may vary, but its superior advantages have been highly exaggerated, as far as my experience goes..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AppArmor is enabled by default on Debian (and I believe Ubuntu), so yes, it is clearly being used in production environments.  In addition, it is typically used to constrain containers, such as those used by Docker.

Many of the default profiles contain apps with poor security histories or services that use protocols with poor security histories, such as pidgin or DNS servers.  It is, of course, possible to constrain additional processes with additional profiles, but I don't know of any organizations which do that on their production services, although clearly some exist.

I do roughly agree with the sentiment you express, that SELinux has the potential to provide more fine-grained control than AppArmor, but, as you note, that AppArmor is easier to configure.  Note that in many cases, a security tool which is easier to use can provide more security than a tool which provides stronger guarantees but is harder to use, because more people can use the tool and use it correctly.  The SELinux Wikipedia page has [more details on the comparison between the two](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux#Comparison_with_AppArmor).

My experience is that Red Hat-based systems tend to use SELinux, and Debian-based systems are more likely to use AppArmor.  That's just because they're the respective defaults, and in many cases, getting one of these MAC systems into a functional state requires help from the distro.  I doubt very much that using both together would result in a meaningfully functional system, so I don't think that's in common use.